# Select records for players that played both types of games

Tags: sql, sql-server, group

I have the following tables:

| Table X |
| --- |
| PlayerID |
| Cellphone |
| FirstName |
| LastName |

| Table Y (gametypes) |
| --- |
| GameName |
| GameTypeID |
| GameID |

| Table Z |
| --- |
| PlayerID |
| GameID |

How do I retrieve only players that played both types of games?

```
GameTypeID = 222 AND (GameName like '%pjp%' OR GameName not like '%pjp%')
```

I mean not to return players that played only one type of these games.
I tried this, but it returns also games that are not  `GameTypeID = 222`

```
select distinct Z.PlayerID, X.CellPhone, X.FirstName, X.LastName from X pb 
join Y g on pb.GameID = g.GameID 
join X p on p.PlayerID = pb.PlayerID 
WHERE g.GameTypeID =222 AND (g.GameName like '%pjp%'  OR g.GameName not like '%pjp%') 
GROUP BY pb.PlayerID,p.CellPhone, p.FirstName, p.LastName, g.GameTypeID
```

Comment: I have not tested but you can try this - select distinct Z.PlayerID, X.CellPhone, X.FirstName, X.LastName from X pb join Y g on pb.GameID = g.GameID join X p on p.PlayerID = pb.PlayerID WHERE  (g.GameName like '%pjp%'  OR g.GameName not like '%pjp%') GROUP BY pb.PlayerID,p.CellPhone, p.FirstName, p.LastName, g.GameTypeID HAVING g.GameTypeID =222

Comment: Even when I added this it didnt help and still return the players that also have gametypes <>222

Comment: select distinct pb.PlayerID, p.CellPhone, p.FirstName, p.LastName from Z pb 
join Y g on pb.GameID = g.GameID
join X p on p.PlayerID = pb.PlayerID
WHERE (g.GameName like '%pjp%' OR g.GameName not like '%pjp%')
GROUP BY pb.PlayerID,p.CellPhone, p.FirstName, p.LastName, g.GameTypeID 
HAVING g.GameTypeID =222 AND g.GameTypeID NOT IN (223,224)

Comment: Please add further updates/details [directly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77270519/edit) to the question

Comment: `AND (GameName like '%pjp%' OR GameName not like '%pjp%')` this part makes no sense, it's like writing `AND 1 = 1` and can be removed altogether (unless GameName is NULL that is). You should post some sample data so it's possible to understand what you want.

Comment: I do not understand your request. You wrote "How do I retrieve only players that played both types of games?" and also "it returns also games that are not GameTypeID = 222". Do you want to retrieve players that played both types of games or that played only the GameTypeID = 222 game?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return all the entries from `Table Z`(`Mapping` as I named it), with more than one entry for a given player. In order to obtain that, you can use the `HAVING` clause. A basic example on how to use it:

```
SELECT PlayerId
FROM Mapping 
GROUP BY PlayerId
HAVING COUNT(PlayerId)>1;
```

If you want to eliminate some of the games based on their type, you need to `JOIN` the tables and use the `WHERE` clause to eliminate the games that you do not want to be taken into consideration.

I have also created a minimal [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/195c627/1) that would better describe what the solution should look like for you.

For more details about join types, you can read [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) article.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

```
SELECT p1.PlayerID, p1.Cellphone, p1.FirstName, p1.LastName
FROM X p1
INNER JOIN Z pz1 ON p1.PlayerID = pz1.PlayerID
INNER JOIN Y g1 ON pz1.GameID = g1.GameID
INNER JOIN Y g2 ON g1.GameName LIKE '%pjp%' AND g2.GameTypeID = 222
LEFT JOIN Z pz2 ON p1.PlayerID = pz2.PlayerID AND pz2.GameID = g2.GameID
WHERE g1.GameTypeID = 222
GROUP BY p1.PlayerID, p1.Cellphone, p1.FirstName, p1.LastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g1.GameID) = 2;
```

Added HAVING clause to verify that the count of distinct GameIDs is equal to 2, indicating that the player has indeed played both types of games.

Answer (score 0):

You can `INTERSECT` the 2 sets

```
SELECT Z.PlayerID
FROM Z
JOIN Y ON Y.GameID = Z.GameID
WHERE Y.GameName LIKE '%pjp%'
INTERSECT
SELECT Z.PlayerID
FROM Z
JOIN Y ON Y.GameID = Z.GameID
WHERE Y.GameName NOT LIKE '%pjp%'
```